# columns referencing each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

Let's say there is a table that contains data rows as below.

[image]

As you see above, Applicant 79 has a twin 80 and Twin 80 has Applicant 79 as a twin.

Since ID 11 and 12 are really the same information, I am wishing to select a unique twin data as following.

[image]

How can I achieve this in SQL Server?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: And please add data as formatted text (not images), for bonus points use DDL/DML statements to create sample data we can use for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
select * from t where ApplicantId < TwinId
```

Comment: @AJ . . . For the sample data, this is the best solution.  For more general situations (ie. not all rows are unique and have a matching pair), none of the answers here work.

Answer (score 2):

One option uses `not exists`

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.applicantid = t.twinid
        and t1.twinid = t.applicantid
        and t1.applicantid < t.applicantid
)
```

When mirror records are present, this retains the record with the smallest `applicantid`.